# how to add AT commands in UART (atmega16) coding to send an sms to a mobile?

Tags: java, c

I used C-lang for UART coding. I know AT commands but a bit confused about how to include them in my UART program

Comment: The question is not clear. What kind of AT commands? Have you got a simple .h? What's about your UART management?

Comment: AT commands are to communicate with the SIM900 gsm modem.generally we implement those  AT commands  using a PUTTY to send or receive the message using a gsm modem. My doubt is how to add those AT commands in UART coding of atmega 16.

Comment: In the same way: imagine your buffer as the putty input. This mean that your array[] contains chars of AT commands. E.g. AT+CPIN=1234 will be "AT+CPIN=1234"

Comment: comment box is too small .how can i include my UART code here?

Comment: SIR , can you plz clarify my doubt with a sample code.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple trace to you:

```
const char *ATCommands[] = { "CGMI", "CGMM" };

char bufferTX[128];
int command_len= 0;

command_len = sprintf(bufferTX, "AT+%s", ATCommand[commandToSend]);

if (command_len > 3)
{
   UART_send(bufferTX, command_len);
}
```

Take note that some onswer of AT protocol (from slave) could be **unssolicited**. It is not an handshake protocol.